# Why is this express route returning a 200 status code when the code says to return a 500?

Tags: node.js, express

I have this route that is expcted to return a 500 status code.

```
/* Return all the users id */
router.post('/user/list', async function (req, res, next) {
    const data = await scanAll(req.body.port, req.body.ip);
     console.log("data ", data) //data 500
    if (data === 500) {
        res.json({
            error: "Error, server connection refused"
        }).status(500);
    }
    else if (data.length === 0) {
        res.json(data).status(204)
    } else {
        res.json(data).status(200);
    }

})
```

It scans a redis server and returns the data.

Well my front end received the json of the error. But receives the 200 status code. Same goes for postman

[image]

How is that possible?

Comment: You should first set the status code `res.status(500).json(data)`

Comment: Try `res.status(500).json(...)` I think you need to set the status first. The `json` function sends the data and if no status is set it sets it to default which is 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Express API: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status

You need to call `status` before calling `json` or `send`

```
res.status(400).send('Bad Request')
res.status(500).json({ error: "Error, server connection refused" })
```

Refer examples from,

- https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send
- https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json
- https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status

So change the above snippet to,

```
/* Return all the users id */
router.post('/user/list', async function (req, res, next) {
    const data = await scanAll(req.body.port, req.body.ip);
     console.log("data ", data) //data 500
    if (data === 500) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Error, server connection refused"
        });
    }
    else if (data.length === 0) {
        res.status(204).json(data);
    } else {
        res.status(200).json(data);
    }

})
```